# How to use tokio's UdpSocket to handle messages in a 1 server: N clients setup?

Tags: rust, udp, closures, future, rust-tokio

**What I want to do:**

... write a (1) server/ (N) clients (network-game-)architecture that uses UDP sockets as underlying base for communication.

- Messages are sent as `Vec<u8>`, encoded via `bincode` (crate)
- I also want to be able to occasionally send datagrams that can exceed the typical max `MTU` of ~`1500 bytes` and be correctly assembled on receiver end, including sending of `ack`-messages etc. ***(I assume I'll have to implement that myself, right?)***

For the `UdpSocket` I thought about using `tokio`'s implementation and maybe `framed`. I am not sure whether this is a good choice though, as it seems that this would introduce an unnecessary step of mapping `Vec<u8>` (serialized by `bincode`) to `Vec<u8>` (needed by `UdpCodec` of `tokio`) (?)

Consider this minimal code-example:

Cargo.toml (server)

```
bincode = "1.0"
futures = "0.1"
tokio-core = "^0.1"
```

(`Serde` and `serde-derive` are used in `shared` crate where the protocol is defined!)

(I want to replace `tokio-core` with `tokio` asap)

```
fn main() -> () {
    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{port}", port = 8080);
    let addr = addr.parse::<SocketAddr>().expect(&format!("Couldn't create valid SocketAddress out of {}", addr));

    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&addr, &handle).expect(&format!("Couldn't bind socket to address {}", addr));


    let udp_future = socket.framed(MyCodec {}).for_each(|(addr, data)| {
        socket.send_to(&data, &addr); // Just echo back the data
        Ok(())
    });

    core.run(udp_future).unwrap();
}

struct MyCodec;

impl UdpCodec for MyCodec {
    type In = (SocketAddr, Vec<u8>);
    type Out = (SocketAddr, Vec<u8>);

    fn decode(&mut self, src: &SocketAddr, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<Self::In> {
        Ok((*src, buf.to_vec()))
    }

    fn encode(&mut self, msg: Self::Out, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> SocketAddr {
        let (addr, mut data) = msg;
        buf.append(&mut data);
        addr
    }
}
```

The problem here is:

> let udp_future = socket.framed(MyCodec {}).for_each(|(addr, data)| {
>       |                          ------ value moved here                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value captured here after move
>       |
>       = note: move occurs because `socket` has type `tokio_core::net::UdpSocket`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

The error makes total sense, yet I am not sure how I would create such a simple echo-service. In reality, the handling of a message involves a bit more logic ofc, but for the sake of a minimal example, this should be enough to give a rough idea.

My workaround is an ugly hack: creating a second socket.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. For example, your import statements (`extern crate ...` / `use ...`) are missing, so we can't even tell what types you are using. Remove all unneeded detail (do you *really* need the logger calls?). What versions of the crates are you using (these crates are still under active development)?

Comment: *`expect(&format!("Couldn't create valid SocketAddress out of {}", addr))`* — don't do that, it allocates the `String` every time that function is called, not just when there's an error. Use `unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("Couldn't create valid SocketAddress out of {}: {}", addr, e))` instead.

Comment: Your `main` function references `self` — the code you've provided cannot *possibly* compile.

Comment: @Shepmaster so it allocates a string once, as it's only called once. But thanks anyways, that was valuable input. And yes, as I tried to create a minimal (albeit incomplete ;)) example, I just put everything into the main function that actually resides in a struct... my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the signature of [`UdpSocket::framed`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio-core/tokio_core/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.framed) from Tokio's documentation:

```
pub fn framed<C: UdpCodec>(self, codec: C) -> UdpFramed<C>
```

Note that it takes `self`, not `&self`; that is, calling this function consumes the socket. The `UdpFramed` wrapper owns the underlying socket when you call this. Your compilation error is telling you that you're moving `socket` when you call this method, but you're also trying to borrow `socket` inside your closure (to call `send_to`).

This probably isn't what you want for real code. The whole point of using `framed()` is to turn your socket into something higher-level, so you can send your codec's items directly instead of having to assemble datagrams. Using `send` or `send_to` directly on the socket will probably break the framing of your message protocol. In this code, where you're trying to implement a simple echo server, you don't need to use `framed` at all. But if you do want to *have your cake and eat it* and use both `framed` and `send_to`, luckily `UdpFramed` still allows you to borrow the underlying `UdpSocket`, using [`get_ref`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio-core/tokio_core/net/struct.UdpFramed.html#method.get_ref). You can fix your problem this way:

```
let framed = {
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&addr, &handle).expect(&format!("Couldn't bind socket to address {}", addr));
    socket.framed(MyCodec {})
}

let udp_future = framed.for_each(|(addr, data)| {
    info!(self.logger, "Udp packet received from {}: length: {}", addr, data.len());
    framed.get_ref().send_to(&data, &addr); // Just echo back the data

    Ok(())
});
```

I haven't checked this code, since (as Shepmaster rightly pointed out) your code snippet has other problems, but it should give you the idea anyway. I'll repeat my warning from earlier: if you do this in real code, it will break the network protocol you're using. `get_ref`'s documentation puts it like this:

> Note that care should be taken to not tamper with the underlying stream of data coming in as it may corrupt the stream of frames otherwise being worked with.

---

To answer the new part of your question: yes, you need to handle reassembly yourself, which means your codec does actually need to do some framing on the bytes you're sending. Typically this might involve a *start sequence* which cannot occur in the `Vec<u8>`. The start sequence lets you recognise the start of the next message after a packet was lost (which happens a lot with UDP). If there's no byte sequence that can't occur in the `Vec<u8>`, you need to escape it when it does occur. You might then send the length of the message, followed by the data itself; or just the data, followed by an end sequence and a checksum so you know none was lost. There are pros and cons to these designs, and it's a big topic in itself.

You also need your `UdpCodec` to contain data: a map from `SocketAddr` to the partially-reassembled message that's currently in progress. In `decode`, if you are given the start of a message, copy it into the map and return `Ok`. If you are given the middle of a message, and you already have the start of a message in the map (for that `SocketAddr`), append the buffer to the existing buffer and return `Ok`. When you get to the end of the message, return the whole thing and empty the buffer. The methods on `UdpCodec` take `&mut self` in order to enable this use case. (**NB** In theory, you should also deal with packets arriving out of order, but that's actually quite rare in the real world.)

`encode` is a lot simpler: you just need to add the same framing and copy the message into the buffer.

Let me reiterate here that you don't need to and shouldn't use the underlying socket after calling `framed()` on it. `UdpFramed` is both a source and a sink, so you use that one object to send the replies as well. You can even use `split()` to get separate `Stream` and `Sink` implementations out of it, if that makes the ownership easier in your application.

---

Overall, now I've seen how much of the problem you're struggling with, I'd recommend just using several TCP sockets instead of UDP. If you want a connection-oriented, reliable protocol, TCP already exists and does that for you. It's very easy to spend a lot of time making a "reliable" layer on top of UDP that is both slower and less reliable than TCP.

Comment: I wonder what's the right way to do this then with Tokio. The whole benefit for me was that I didn't need to create the datagrams by hand.

Comment: Also, I guess it brings in the exact same error, doesn't it? (Will try once at home)... I mean we invoke the `for_each` on `framed` and use `framed` inside the closure.